# Python validating class attributes

Tags: python, environment-variables

I need to write simple Python script for validating some system ENV variables. And I can do it with simplest code like a:

```
#test.py

import os
import sys

validation_errors = []

min_resources_count = os.environ.get('RESOURCES_MIN')
max_resources_count = os.environ.get('RESOURCES_MAX')

if int(min_resources_count) > int(max_resources_count):
  validation_errors.append('Maximum value must be greater than or equal to minimum value')

if int(max_resources_count) == 0:
  validation_errors.append('Maximum value cannot be zero')

...
# And so on...
...

if validation_errors:
  sys.stderr.write(validation_errors) # will add some formatting
```

But, something inside me says that it can be written better. Maybe it can be moved inside some class, something like this:

```
class SystemEnvValidation:
  def __init__(self):
    self.min_resources_count = os.environ.get('RESOURCES_MIN')
    self.max_resources_count = os.environ.get('RESOURCES_MAX')

    self.validation_errors = []

  def max_resources_count(self):
    # place IF conditions here
    if int(self.max_resources_count) == 0:
       self.validation_errors.append('Maximum value cannot be zero')
    ...

 print(SystemEnvValidation().validation_errors)
```

So, my question is - what is the best way to implement it? Should I place it in class? Or maybe I can leave it as is? In the case of class - I am not familiar with Python classes - could you show me simple working code structure?

Comment: Generally, see [pydantic](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/) for data validation.

Comment: @jarmod thank you, will check, but I want to write a simple own code with minimal external libraries =)